# Is it a good idea to call virtual function in copy assignment(operator=)?

Tags: c++

As we known, we should not call virtual function in constructor or destructor.

I am wondering whether we should not call virtual function in copy assignment (operator=)either?

Comment: Well, one "bad" idea is if your copy operations are lying to us, i.e. not really making actual copies.  Those are some of the hardest bugs to find, and that is when the copy assignment operations aren't doing what they say they are doing -- making copies.   So use any function you want, *so long as what you're doing is making copies*.

Answer (score 7):

Virtual functions will work as they normally do in copy assignment operators. Only constructors and destructors are special in this regard. That said, whether it is a "good idea" depends on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: could you please give an example that call virtual function in operator= is good?

Comment: @camino I can't think of an example where it would be a good idea. That doesn't mean I think there isn't one.

Comment: If the design requires it and it is not called a million times, maybe it's ok. If the copy assignment is used frequently enough that a virtual function call will affect the performance, you should rethink the design.